# Getting "'gem (at master) is not checked out. Run 'bundle install' first" every time I run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, bundle

After a long period without using Ruby on Rails on MacBook (OSX 10.9), every time I run

```
    rake db:migrate
```

or

```
    bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

I get the following errorr:

```
 git://github.com/capistrano/capistrano.git (at master) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first.
```

I've already run the    bundle install, but still not working.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try `bundle exec rake db:create`.

Comment: Are you using something like RVM?

If so make sure that RVM is actually loaded.

Comment: @Pavan already tried. Still not working. Getting the same Error

Comment: @IanRodriguez Yes, I'm using it. How do I make sure of it? This error only happens when I'm running an older version of Rails, such as 3.2.1.

Comment: run `rvm info` to see if you are using rvm ruby or system (you want to be using rvm), also after running `bundle install` verify that the gems are installed with `bundle exec gem list` and to check if capistrano is installed, try `bundle exec gem list | grep capistrano`

Comment: Did you try removing and installing the capistrano gem again?

Answer (score 4):

Try :

```
 Bundle install --deployment
```

Comment: my bundle (install) have same problem with rails-5.1.1 and later. with --deployment it's work! Thk